# Why am I getting InaccessibleObjectException when writing to JSON file

Tags: exception, javafx, gson

I'm using Gson to manage my Json file. I have a User class which looks like this:

public class User {

```
private StringProperty username;
private StringProperty password;

...

public User() {}

public User(String user, String pass, ...) {

    this.username = new SimpleStringProperty(user);
    this.password = new SimpleStringProperty(pass);

    ...

}

public String getUsername() {
    return username.get();
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username.set(username);;
}

...

}
```

And this is how I add a User to the Json file

```
public static boolean addUser(User user) throws IOException{

    String users = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("users.json")));

    List<User> userList = getUsers(users);

    if (userList.contains(user)) return false;

    userList.add(user);

    Writer writer = new FileWriter("users.json");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    gson.toJson(userList, writer);
    writer.close();

    return true;

}
```

gson.toJson(userList, writer) is throwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty.bean accessible: module javafx.base does not "opens javafx.beans.property" to unnamed module @4bf59938
```

I know it has something to do with the StringProperty attributes, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The clue can be found here: `module javafx.base does not "opens javafx.beans.property" to unnamed module`. Can you post how you run your JavaFX project (command line, maven, gradle)?

Comment: @JoséPereda it's command line through Eclipse

Comment: Ok, and what is the `java` command line? It looks like you are missing the required VM arguments. You can find more about this here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse

Comment: @JoséPereda I had already read that post. These are my VM Arguments:

--module-path C:/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Since you are using Gson, probably there is some internal use of reflection going on, so that will require also `--add-opens javafx.base/javafx.beans.property=ALL-UNNAMED`, can you try it?

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm getting the same exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200395/discussion-between-awesomeguy-and-jose-pereda).

Comment: The idea of sterilizing Property is bad. You only need to serialize the User data. So make a POJO object that contains data only (DTO). Also make a decorator to give the desired fx properties.

Comment: I recommend using a json library that supports the use of getters/setters instead. I don't know about any serialization library that is able to deal with javafx properties; Using a library that does not need to deal with those directly would be preferrable. E.g. Jackson should allow you to do this. Gson though uses fields only.